# BaseDN syntax use with LDAP

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to retreive the information of user using the user's id from Ldap internal server.

I've already a script to get the informations from my OU but i'd like to get the informations of an user from any OU. (it can be from any OU of my enterprise.

I hope you could help me :)

```
            $ldap = ldap_connect("LDAP://xxxxxxxx/", 389)
            or die;

        $ldapuser      = 'user'; 
        $ldappass     = 'pass';

        $BaseDN = "OU=Utilisateurs,OU=AF,OU=M_Viy,OU=Ressources_Locales,DC=COMMUN,DC=AD,DC=xxxx,DC=FR";
    //  $RootDN = 'CN=LDAP User,OU=Comptes_Generiques_Attente,OU=M_Vitry,OU=Ressources_Locales,DC=COMMUN,DC=AD,DC=xxxxx,DC=FR';
    //  $ConnectionFilter = '(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))';

        if ($bind = ldap_bind($ldap, $ldapuser, $ldappass)) 
        {
            $attributes_ad = array("displayName","givenname","sn","samaccountname","telephonenumber","mail","extensionattribute7","mobile","company","displayName");

            $cpuser = $infos['user'];
            $result = ldap_search($ldap, $BaseDN, "samaccountname=$cpuser", $attributes_ad);
            $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);

            print_r($info);
        }
```

Comment: What OS is this running on? I've achieved something similar on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest changing your Base DN from

```
$BaseDN = "OU=Utilisateurs,OU=AF,OU=M_Viy,OU=Ressources_Locales,DC=COMMUN,DC=AD,DC=xxxx,DC=FR";
```

to just

```
$BaseDN = "DC=COMMUN,DC=AD,DC=xxxx,DC=FR";
```

and setting the appropriate filter. So instead of `"samaccountname=$cpuser"`, try using

`"(&(objectCategory=person)(sAMAccountName=*))"`
.

This should allow you to get any user from any OU within your domain.

Comment: Thanks. I've this error : "Warning: ldap_search(): Search: Operations error in C:\WWW2\login_ldap.php on line 29"

Comment: Sorry, I noticed you didn't have LDAP options set. after your `$ldap` declaration, try adding `ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);` and `ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);`

Comment: Glad I could help!